# How to delete a relationship from many to many table in sqlite-net extension?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I've a many to many relationship between students and classes using [`SQLite-net Extensions`](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions):

```
public class Students
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(Students_Classes))]
    public List<Classes> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class Classes
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(Students_Classes))]
    public List<Students> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Students_Classes
{
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Students))]
    public int StudentFId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Classes))]
    public int ClassFId { get; set; }
}
```

I add a relationship this way:

```
dbConnection.InsertOrReplace(new Students_Classes { StudentFId = sId, ClassFId = cId });
```

But when I want to delete a relationship:

```
var validRelation = dbConnection.Find<Students_Classes>(x => x.StudentFId = sId && x.ClassFId = cId);
if (validRelation == null)
    return;

dbConnection.Delete(validRelation);
```

I get an error says `cannot delete because it has no PK`. I can get a Student with all his classes, remove one class then save it again with his classes but there can be performance issues.

How to remove a relationship in a many to many relationship? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy, just add a primary key to your relationship class:

```
public class Students_Classes
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Students))]
    public int StudentFId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Classes))]
    public int ClassFId { get; set; }
}
```

Anyway using SQLite-Net Extensions you don't need to manage the relationship table by yourself, just add or remove the children item from the list and call `UpdateWithChildren` on the object.

Take a look at the Integration Tests project to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks @redent84. I thought there should be performance issues if call `GetWithChildren()`, add the children item and then save them all again?

Comment: Well, if that's the case you're correct. It doesn't make sense to load all elements just to delete one of them. Maybe I can add a convenience method for that in the API.