# fully delete a relationship in a many to many table in sqlite-net extension?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I have a similar situation, to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412411/how-to-delete-a-relationship-from-many-to-many-table-in-sqlite-net-extension/35201219#35201219) the delete works but only on students and classes table, in the student_classes table the elements are not deleted.

```
  public class Students
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(Students_Classes))]
    public List<Classes> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class Classes
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(Students_Classes))]
    public List<Students> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Students_Classes
{
   [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int StudentClassesId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Students))]
    public int StudentFId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Classes))]
    public int ClassFId { get; set; }
}
```

To delete I use the following code

```
conn.Delete(student, true);
```

I have no problem during insert and updates
thanks

p.s. My classes have different names, but doesn't matter, the code is really identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cascade deletion [doesn't remove intermediate records](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/issues/21/delete-recursive-true-with-a-manytomany). These records are harmless, but completely useless, you can remove them manually. For example:

```
// Fetch IDs of intermediate records to delete
var deleteIds = conn.Table<Student_Classes>()
    .Where(e => e.StudentFId == student.StudentId)
    .Select(e => e.StudentFId).ToList();

// Perform batch deletion
conn.DeleteAllIds<Student_Classes>(deleteIds);
```

Or more performant (but less refactor friendly):

```
var deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Student_Classes WHERE StudentFId == ?";
conn.Execute(deleteQuery, student.StudentId);
```

Comment: thanks! this was what I was worried about, meanwhile I already used this "workaround"

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a primary key in your Students_Classes class. That is the problem.

Comment: damn sorry, of course I have, I followed the comments in the post I linked, I just copied and pasted from the link and not from my code :/ Thanks !